# jquery calculation - NaN and formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.field.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.calculation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

$(function() {
      $('input[name^=sum]').keyup(function() {
            var sum1 = parseFloat($('input[name=sum1]').val());
            var sum2 = parseFloat($('input[name=sum2]').val()); 
    var sum3 = parseFloat($('input[name=sum3]').val()); 


            $('#c_card_amount').val(sum1*sum3/100);
    $('#total_inc_charges').val((sum1*sum3/100)+sum1);
    });
});

</script>
```

My questions:

1. If no value is in `sum1` the `c_card_amount` and the `total_inc_charges` are `NaN`. How can I put a condition in this that says if no value is in `sum1` just show 0 in `total_inc_charges`. I've read about this but I could not figure out the answer in terms of my code.
2. My second question is: how can I show the numbers in 1,000.00 format for instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a **short-circuit operator**. If the result of `parseFloat()` == `NaN`, the value will be set to zero.

```
var sum1 = parseFloat($('input[name=sum1]').val()) || 0;
var sum2 = parseFloat($('input[name=sum2]').val()) || 0; 
var sum3 = parseFloat($('input[name=sum3]').val()) || 0;
```

**Additional Information:**

See [MDN Expressions and Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)

Comment: I would use the good'n old conditional (ternary) operator. "condition ? val1 : val2" like in "(x > 0) ? x : 0;"

Comment: @Alfabravo, that would work, but I think my solution is little better.  Using your solution inline, jquery would have to retrieve `$('input[name=sum1]').val()` twice. If you didn't do it inline, additional code would be needed to change the values from `NaN` to 0.

Comment: Could you help me with the number formatting problem, please? 
  I have tried this:

Comment: @Peter, I'd be happy to. First things first. Vote this question up by clicking the up arrow, then click the check mark to mark this as the answer. After that, post another question about the number formatting issue. It's a bit more work, but you'll get much better answers then when you ask questions in the comments. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: I wanted to. but it says i can vote up after i've gained at least 15 reputation something :)

Comment: @Peter, post your number formatting question, I'll look out for it :)